# Making an exam grader in python [lists related question]

Tags: python, list

I am making a program that asks the user to enter in responses to multiple choice questions, and then they supply an answer key. After that, the program grades the exam, gives them a score, and tells them what question number they got wrong, what their response was, and what the correct answer is.

Here is a sample run of my program:

```
Welcome to gradermatic.
To enter responses, enter 1.
To enter an answer key, enter 2.
To grade, enter 3.
Press any other key to quit. >> 1
How many questions are there? >> 3

What is your answer for question #1 >> a

What is your answer for question #2 >> a

What is your answer for question #3 >> a

Responses:

1. a
2. a
3. a
Welcome to gradermatic.
To enter responses, enter 1.
To enter an answer key, enter 2.
To grade, enter 3.
Press any other key to quit. >> 2

What is the correct answer for question #1 >> a

What is the correct answer for question #2 >> c

What is the correct answer for question #3 >> d

Responses:

1. a
2. c
3. d
Welcome to gradermatic.
To enter responses, enter 1.
To enter an answer key, enter 2.
To grade, enter 3.
Press any other key to quit. >> 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 99, in <module>
    a.start()
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 9, in start
    a.enterResponses()
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 38, in enterResponses
    a.start() # take us back to the main menu
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 12, in start
    a.answerKey()
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 55, in answerKey
    a.start()
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 15, in start
    a.grade()
  File "/Users/faiqashraf/Desktop/github site/PersonalProjects/grader/grader.py", line 68, in grade
    goingIn = "#" + str(self.responses.index(p)) + " user entered: " + str(self.responses(p))+ " correct answer: " + str(self.answers(q))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

and here is my code:

```
class Grader:
def start(self):
    # greeting message
    o = input("Welcome to gradermatic.\nTo enter responses, enter 1.\nTo enter an answer key, enter 2.\nTo grade, enter 3.\nPress any other key to quit. >> ")
    if o == "1":
        # enter responses
        self.numOfQuestions = input("How many questions are there? >> ")
        a.enterResponses()
    elif o == "2":
        # enter answer key
        a.answerKey()
    elif o == "3":
        # grade the exam
        a.grade()
    # get number of questions

def enterResponses(self):
    # start gathering answers
    i = 1
    self.responses = []
    while i <= int(self.numOfQuestions):
        entry = input("\nWhat is your answer for question #" + str(i) + " >> ")
        self.responses += entry
        i += 1

    # display user responses
    print("\nResponses:\n")
    j = 1
    for r in self.responses:
        print(str(j) + ". " + r)
        j+=1
    # change any answers?
    # change = input("Would you like to change any answers? 1 = yes, 2 = no")
    # if change == "1":
    #     a.changeAns()

    a.start() # take us back to the main menu

def answerKey(self):
    # input answer key
    x = 1
    self.answers = []
    while x <= int(self.numOfQuestions):
        aentry = input("\nWhat is the correct answer for question #" + str(x) + " >> ")
        self.answers += aentry
        x += 1

    # display answer key
    print("\nResponses:\n")
    y = 1
    for z in self.answers:
        print(str(y) + ". " + z)
        y+=1
    a.start()

def grade(self):
    # grade the responses
    # time to actually grade the exam
    numCorrect = 0
    self.incorrect = []
    for p, q in zip(self.responses, self.answers):
        if p == q:
            # correct answer, so add 1 to their score
            numCorrect += 1
        else:
            # incorrect answer, note:the question number                           user entry                                  correct answer
            goingIn = "#" + str(self.responses.index(p)) + " user entered: " + str(self.responses(p))+ " correct answer: " + str(self.answers(q))
            self.incorrect += goingIn
            goingIn = "" # reset, incase we need to add more stuff


    # issue a grade
    print(str(numCorrect))
    print("Number of correct answers = " + str(numCorrect) + " out of " + str(self.numOfQuestions))
    grade = int(numCorrect) / int(self.numOfQuestions)
    print("Your score is: " + str(grade))

    # display incorrect answers:
    print("Here are the questions the user got wrong, as well as their correct answers:")
    for l in self.incorrect:
        print(l)

    # end the program
    exit(0)

    # def changeAns(self):
    #     # time to change answers
    #     whatToChange = input("What question's answer do you want to change? Enter a number between 1 and " + str(numOfQuestions))
    #     if whatToChange <= int(numOfQuestions):
    #         # change the answer
    #         newAns = input("What do you want the answer to be? >> ")
    #         responses[whatToChange] == newAns



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Grader()
    a.start()
```

My question is this: How can I make note of the 3 criteria for telling the user that they got the question wrong? Recall that those 3 criteria are:

1. The question number that they got wrong
2. What answer they supplied as a response
3. What the correct answer is

I tried getting the question number via .index from the list, and the iterator for the response and answer that the program was on while grading the text (p and q).

Any and all solutions are welcome! Also if you have a better program name than gradermatic, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues in here. First, `a` is the variable name you gave the instance of `Grader` class. It should not be referred to inside the class itself, use `self` instead. The error you received came from this line because you tried treating the lists as functions.

```
goingIn = "#" + str(self.responses.index(p)) + " user entered: " + str(self.responses(p))+ " correct answer: " + str(self.answers(q))
```

You are already iterating over the lists, so all you need to do is print `p` and `q`:

```
goingIn = "#" + str(self.responses.index(p)) + " user entered: " + p + " correct answer: " + q
```

Finally, the line `self.incorrect += goingIn` will behave like `list(str)`, and create a separate list entry for each letter in the string. Instead you should use the `append()` list method.

```
self.incorrect.append(goingIn)
```

And now it will run to completion.

```
Welcome to gradermatic.
To enter responses, enter 1.
To enter an answer key, enter 2.
To grade, enter 3.
Press any other key to quit. >> 1
How many questions are there? >> 3

What is your answer for question #1 >> a

What is your answer for question #2 >> a

What is your answer for question #3 >> a

Responses:

1. a
2. a
3. a
Welcome to gradermatic.
To enter responses, enter 1.
To enter an answer key, enter 2.
To grade, enter 3.
Press any other key to quit. >> 2

What is the correct answer for question #1 >> a

What is the correct answer for question #2 >> b

What is the correct answer for question #3 >> a

Responses:

1. a
2. b
3. a
Welcome to gradermatic.
To enter responses, enter 1.
To enter an answer key, enter 2.
To grade, enter 3.
Press any other key to quit. >> 3
2
Number of correct answers = 2 out of 3
Your score is: 0.6666666666666666
Here are the questions the user got wrong, as well as their correct answers:
#0 user entered: a correct answer: b
```

Here is the edited `Grader` class.

```
class Grader:
    def start(self):
        o = input("Welcome to gradermatic.\nTo enter responses, enter 1.\nTo enter an answer key, enter 2.\nTo grade, enter 3.\nPress any other key to quit. >> ")
        if o == "1":
            self.numOfQuestions = input("How many questions are there? >> ")
            self.enterResponses()
        elif o == "2":
            self.answerKey()
        elif o == "3":
            self.grade()

    def enterResponses(self):
        i = 1
        self.responses = []
        while i <= int(self.numOfQuestions):
            entry = input("\nWhat is your answer for question #" + str(i) + " >> ")
            self.responses += entry
            i += 1

        print("\nResponses:\n")
        j = 1
        for r in self.responses:
            print(str(j) + ". " + r)
            j+=1

        self.start() # take us back to the main menu

    def answerKey(self):
        x = 1
        self.answers = []
        while x <= int(self.numOfQuestions):
            aentry = input("\nWhat is the correct answer for question #" + str(x) + " >> ")
            self.answers += aentry
            x += 1

        print("\nResponses:\n")
        y = 1
        for z in self.answers:
            print(str(y) + ". " + z)
            y+=1
        self.start()

    def grade(self):
        numCorrect = 0
        self.incorrect = []
        for p, q in zip(self.responses, self.answers):
            if p == q:
                numCorrect += 1
            else:
                goingIn = "#" + str(self.responses.index(p)) + " user entered: " + p + " correct answer: " + q
                self.incorrect.append(goingIn)
                goingIn = "" # reset, incase we need to add more stuff


        # issue a grade
        print(str(numCorrect))
        print("Number of correct answers = " + str(numCorrect) + " out of " + str(self.numOfQuestions))
        grade = int(numCorrect) / int(self.numOfQuestions)
        print("Your score is: " + str(grade))

        print("Here are the questions the user got wrong, as well as their correct answers:")
        for l in self.incorrect:
            print(l)

        exit(0)
```